# Override Android versionCode from applied Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle

I want to override the Android `versionCode` property from an applied script file (as to keep the app script clean). This is what i am doing currently (i omitted anything unrelated):

*build.gradle:*

```
apply from: 'ci.gradle'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
    }
}
```

*ci.gradle:*

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.defaultConfig.versionCode = 3434
}
```

But i still end up with `versionCode` being `1`... What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that it can be solved by moving `apply from: 'ci.gradle'` after the `android` block:

*build.gradle*:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
    }
}

apply from: 'ci.gradle'
```

*ci.gradle*:

```
android.defaultConfig.versionCode = 3434
```